# how does cb && 'function' === typeof cb && cb(data) work in the Action(React-redux) with redux-thunk?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I create a mock promise as delay()to access redux-thunk.

In the action part, I could not understand `cb && 'function' === typeof cb && cb(data)` and how does it work in the action with redux-thunk?

```
class Actions {
    static start() {
        return {
            type: actionType.CREATE_TODO_DOING
        }
    }

    static ok(data, cb) {
        cb && 'function' === typeof cb && cb(data);
        return {
            type: actionType.CREATE_TODO_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        }
    }

    static fail(data, cb) {
        cb && 'function' === typeof cb && cb(data);
        return {
            type: actionType.CREATE_TODO_FAILURE,
            payload: data
        }
    }
}

export default (data, cb) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(Actions.start());
        delay(0.5).then(() => {
            dispatch(Actions.ok(data, cb));
        }).catch(error => dispatch(Actions.fail(error || 'Create failed', cb)))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a shortcut for these

```
if (cb && 'function' === typeof cb) { // check cb has value + cb is a function or not
  cb(data); // call cb function
}
```

And it just a callback function that you want to call it when `Actions.ok` function is called, that's it

Comment: thanks, I know the meaning of cb && 'function' === typeof cb, I am still confused, may I ask you why it occurs in the action how does it work?

Comment: Assume you have a action call `LoginSuccess` and this action is called when user login successfully. And after that, you want to trigger something (callback), such as redirect, show message info, ... So, you want this callback is called when action `LoginSuccess` is dispatched. And the callback is the `cb` function in your `Actions.ok`